# Objective c - UIImage resizing issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgimage

I have a resource (.png file) that show a picture frame (border).
This .png file is size 100x100px, and the border width is 10px.

[image: my original image]

**My Question:**

How can I create another UIImage from this image, with a different size, without ruin the border's width?

**The Problem:**

When I try to draw the new image from the original image with `CGContextDrawImage`  I get a new image with the new size, but my border proportion is ruin.

```
        CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
        CGImageRef imageRef = //... the image

        // Build a context that's the same dimensions as the new size
        CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                    newRect.size.width,
                                                    newRect.size.height,
                                                    CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                    0,
                                                    CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                    CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));


        // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, kCGInterpolationHigh);

        // Draw into the context; this scales the image
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, newRect, imageRef);

        // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
        CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

        // Clean up
        CGContextRelease(bitmap);
        CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
```

For example, when I tried to create an image size 800x100p, I get an image with very thin top and bottom border.

[image: the bad result I get]

What I need is that the border will stay the same width
[image]

***note**
Using `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` wont help me, because I need a new image with the new size to save on the disc.

Comment: Does it have to be a resource? I'm sure there's a way to add borders with width and color programmatically. I take it this isn't an option for you(if you'd want a custom border etc), just making sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use resizableImageWithCapInsets:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myResource"];
img = [img resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10)];
```

I've never used this approach with CGContextDrawImage, but it should work.

Comment: resizableImageWithCapInsets: will create a resizableImage, which can be drawn in any size.

Comment: I tried that with no success... You where right if I was using an imageview to present the image, but I write the image to disc, and it look like the resizableImage has no effect on the result...

Comment: What about using drawInRect:, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562742/uiedgeinsets-ignored-on-cgcontextdrawimage-within-a-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextw

Comment: From my experience drawInRect: is slower, so I prefer not to use it. But that can be one posible solution...