# How to use resizableImageWithCapInsets on UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I want to take a picture like this:

[image]

And I wrote the code:

```
[[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] 
  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f)]
  drawInRect:rect];
```

But with this code I took that:

[image]

Why??? How to draw a resized image in rect with fixed 1px on all sides?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14648532/608157) for how to use it

Comment: What are the edges of that image? Any transparent pixels along the border?

Comment: Should I use Stretched mode? And Titled used by default.

Comment: No transparent pixels. I want to fix 1px and resize ALL other content.

Comment: Your border is obviously wider than 1px...

Comment: refer this link it may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562742/uiedgeinsets-ignored-on-cgcontextdrawimage-within-a-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to stretch the image **on iOS 6+**:

```
[[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]drawInRect:rect];
```

Comment: This isn't the correct answer. This will stretch the image without respecting the edge insets specified.